# What actually happens when you log-in while already logged in with OWIN in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

While testing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with user login and authentication, I forgot to make sure that my logged-in users wouldn't be able to access the login form again. So out of curiosity, I decided to test what would happen if I log-in as "USER B" while being logged-in as "User A". The result was that apparently "User A" was logged-out and "User B" got logged-in instead. I emphasize "apparently" because that is what it looks in the front-end, but I'm not sure if the back-end state of the app truly reflects that behavior.

This is my login code (Credits to another StackOverflow post):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
            var authManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

            AppUser user = userManager.Find(login.Email, login.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var ident = userManager.CreateIdentity(user,
                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                authManager.SignIn(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
        return View(login);
    }
```

As you can see, I straight up call the `auth.SignIn` function without proper validation. What truly happened behind the scenes? Or could someone please recommend me documentation that explains this.